# Determining CSS Text width With PHP

Tags: php, css, gd2

I need to determinate text width in my html. I use php GD2 library and calculate text width but calculated width different from chrome developer toolbar width.

```
<?php
$text = 'HELLO WORLD';
$font = './fonts/Helvetica___.ttf';
$fontSize = "12";

$bbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $text);
$width = $bbox[4] - $bbox[0];

echo "point=".$width.'<br>';
echo "pixel=".ceil((($width * 96) / 72)).'<BR>';

echo '<p><span style="font-family: helvetica;font-size:12px;">'.$text.'</span></p>';
exit();
```

Comment: This is a futile exercise.  The width of the text display depends on the content, the font, the rendering engine and the css.  If you really need the width you need to use Javascript and then send it back to the server.  What is your actual requirement?  There may be another solution.

Comment: i need pinterest't home page image location calculation.  you mean it's location can change by text size. i accomplish it %95 with char count but i can't find sometimes exact width text.